# How to order ARRAY in Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

The documentation for ARRAY_AGG ([link](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/functions-and-operators#array_agg)) function says that the elements in the result array will be in random order and that with different starts this order may change.

How can I order elements in the array?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to order arrays, but it will depend on how you would like to order then and how to use this order. I would recommend you to take a look at the below documentation, on how to work with Arrays on Spanner.

There, you will find more information about how to order it and the available options.

- [Working with Arrays](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/arrays)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Answer (score 0):

The ARRAY_AGG clause in Spanner does not currently support ORDER BY

So unfortunately this is currently not allowed:

SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY x) FROM UNNEST([2,1,3,4,2,-1]) as x;

While this is allowed, it will also not work:

SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x) FROM (SELECT x FROM UNNEST([2,1,3,4,2,-1]) as x ORDER BY x);

The options available are:

If you are returning the ARRAY_AGG result to a client, the result can be sorted there

OR

If you must return the data in an order, maybe it is possible you do not have to use the ARRAY_AGG? In which case you can guarantee the ordering with an ORDER BY clause.  This is valid:

SELECT x FROM UNNEST([2,1,3,4,2,-1]) as x ORDER BY x;

The answer may change in the future, so it is a good idea to check on the ARRA_AGG doc ([link](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/functions-and-operators#array_agg)) again if looking at this time